# openmp offloading feature throws error "Intel Compiler compatibility mode was disabled"

Tags: openmp, icx

I try to make use of the openmp offloading feature. Unfortunatley I get some strange error messages when I try to compile. (Windows 10)
Here are the command line options I use:

> /Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /fsycl /Qiopenmp /W3/fsycl-targets=spir64_gen-unknown-unknown-sycldevice /Zi /O2 /Qopenmp-targets:spir64/Qipo /Zc:forScope /MD /std:c++17 /Fa"x64\Release" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release" //fprofile-instr-use "x64\Release" /Fp"x64\Release\AlgoGPU.pch"

I remove the /I and /D
This is what I get during compilation:

> error: Enables or disables Intel Compiler compatibility mode was enabled in PCH file but is currently disabled
> error: PCH file was compiled for the target 'x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.28.29914' but the current translation unit is being compiled for target 'spir64_gen-unknown-unknown-sycldevice'
> 2 errors generated.
> C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\Intel C++ Compiler 2021\Toolset.targets(199,5): error MSB6006: "icx.exe" exited with code 1.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below command line option with oneAPI DPC++/ icx compilers

-fsycl -fsycl-targets=spir64_gen-unknown-unknown-sycldevice /std:c++17 /O2 /Zc:forScope /MD /Qiopenmp /Qopenmp-targets=spir64

Comment: Is this an answer to your own question? Have you tried https://community.intel.com/ ?